# libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect range settings

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I need to change the min and max range of the depth image from libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks,
Pawel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23244/libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect-range-settings/) by [mrsiekierka](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13898/mrsiekierka/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems that the  and   elements will help you :) http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__openni__kinect_8cpp_source.html

---

Originally posted by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) with karma: 68 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1